# Difference between Matlab's imwrite and dct2 for JPEG compression

Tags: matlab, compression, jpeg

Below is a snippet taken from matlab's [website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) describing imwrite:

> `imwrite(___,Name,Value)` specifies additional parameters for output GIF, HDF, JPEG, PBM, PGM, PNG, PPM, and TIFF files, using one or more name-value pair arguments. You can specify Name,Value after the input arguments in any of the previous syntaxes.

Here are some [Name,Value pairs arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#namevaluepairarguments) that you can use for `imwrite` compression:

- 'Compression' — Compression scheme
- 'Quality' — Quality of JPEG-compressed file

So an example of imwrite doing the compression is: `imwrite(A,'C:\project\lena.jpg','jpeg','Quality',Q)` where **Q** is the quality factor.

I'm new to matlab. I read that matlab's `imwrite` is able to do JPEG compression to a specific quality factor (as described above). Hence, I am curious in what is the difference (is there any?) in doing JPEG compression using `imwrite` as compared to `dct2` when all other factors are fixed as much as possible (e.g, same quality factor, same input image source)? Ignoring any difference in computational cost, just focusing on the resulting jpeg image.

#### Update:

I found a [paper](http://dde.binghamton.edu/vholub/pdf/EURASIP14_Universal_Distortion_Function_for_Steganography_in_an_Arbitrary_Domain.pdf) detailing the differences in using these two techniques in **page 4**, section **3.3.1 Technical issues with zero embedding costs**. Here is a snippet taken from the paper:

> When using the slow DCT (implemented using ‘dct2’ in Matlab), the number 1/2-coefficients is small and does not affect security at least for low-quality factors. However, in the fast-integer implementation of DCT (e.g., Matlab’s imwrite), all Dij are multiples of 1/8. Thus, with decreasing quantization step (increasing JPEG quality factor), the number of 1/2-coefficients increases.

The "1/2 coefficients" above refers to the unquantized DCT coefficients having a "0.5" decimal point. It is also known as the "rounding error". Based on this, it seems like there is indeed a difference in the resulting unquantized DCT coefficients for different quality factors.

Comment: JPEG applies DCT to small 8x8 pixel blocks, after converting to Yuv color space and optionally subsampling the u and v channels. It then drops some DCT components, does Huffman encoding and a bunch more steps. The JPEG spec is well documented, I recommend you take a look. But yes, it is a 2D DCT that underlies how it works, and this is the same computations that `dct2` in MATLAB does.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the response. Yes I am aware that dct2 is just a component of the JPEG compression process. But I was just curious as to whether the output of the JPEG compression that `imwrite` offers, will it be different if the same process is applied using `dct2`. Output in terms of the resulting JPEG compressed image, for example, if the quantized DCT coefficients are the same?

Comment: `dct2` computes the same DCT as the JPEG algorithm uses. But it doesn’t do anything else, it doesn’t quantize the coefficients. `dct2` by itself is lossless, you can apply the inverse transform and recover the original values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, you are correct. It is difficult to compare `imwrite` and `dct2` as `imwrite` comprises the whole JPEG compression while `dct2` is just a small portion in the process. In theory, if everything else in the process is fixed as the same, there should not be any differences in the output of JPEG compression either using `imwrite` or `dct2`? I did a small experiment and calculated the PSNR of JPEG compressed images before and after compression using the two techniques and find that the PSNR is the same. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: The difference mentioned in your edit relate to quantization. You can apply `dct2`, and then quantize, to get the same values computed in the JPEG algorithm.

Comment: @CrisLuengo hmm, I am not sure why the paper concluded that there was difference in the two methods. Anyway, quantization is out of scope for this question. Thanks for the help!